# Get result of Database.SqlQuery

Tags: sql, oracle, odp.net

I´ve a MVC 5 Project in VS 2013 with ODP.net Connection to an oracle database and entity framework 6.

I also have a view in my database which holds all information I need for my select call. I need to get all the information out of the database and display it on the webpage. I get the right number of elements in my list, but they are all empty.

I´ve read that my objects have to contain the correct names of the elements, but that isn´t working.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            var result =
                context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntity>(
                    "SELECT (case when HERKUNFT = 'AVZ' then ANLA_NR else LAG_NR end) \"LagerAnlage\", " +
                    "STO_NR \"Standort\", " +
                    "ART_NR \"Artikelnummer\", " +
                    "ART_KBEZ || '\n' || ART_BEZ1 || '\n' || ART_BEZ2 \"Artikelbezeichnung\", " +
                    "SN \"SN\", " +
                    "TO_CHAR(DTZUGANG, 'DD.MM.YYYY') \"Zugangsdatum\", " +
                    "TO_CHAR(DTABGANG, 'DD.MM.YYYY') \"Abgangsdatum\", " +
                    "WERT \"WertStk\", " +
                    "MENGE \"Stk\" " +
                    "FROM view_useravz " +
                    "WHERE user_cd = 'USERNAME' " +
                    "ORDER BY DTZUGANG");

            var list = result.ToList();

        }

        return View();
    }
}

class MyEntity
{
    public string LagerAnlage;
    public string Standort;
    public string Artikelnummer;
    public string Artikelbezeichnung;
    public string SN;
    public string Zugangsdatum;
    public string Abgangsdatum;
    public string WertStk;
    public string Stk;
}
```

Comment: This will return only those rows where the `user_cd` column has the value `USERNAME`. Is that really what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I need all entries for this specific user. USERNAME will be an variable which changes depending on the user who uses the program.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know why, but now I got an Error and was able to find a solution.

I chose the wrong types in my Class. When i set WertStk and Stk to int everything worked.